# Ошибка при создании Google Maps Api в Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps-api, android-studio

После компиляции выбивает

> "This app won't run without google
> play services which are missing from
> your phone."

и ниже кнопка [Update], при нажатии - вылетает, API ключ на Google Maps ввел, в чем проблема?

[image]

Comment: на каком телефоне запускаете?

Comment: Запускаю на эмуляторе.

Comment: @SuperPonchik сколько я не пытался на эмуляторе прикрутить Google Play, у меня ничего не вышло :(

Comment: @argamidon, а почему Google Maps требует доступ Google Play? )

Comment: эмулятор нужен "не простой, а золотой". Google в помощь    
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20google%20maps%20on%20emulator&es_th=1

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо скачать эмулятор с поддержкой Google APIs. Когда создаете новый девайс для тестирования, при скачивании android выберите: версия Android(Google APIs). Вот скрин: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]